# Android exchange notification for custom notification with swipe gesture on each view

Tags: android, notifications, remoteview

I am suffering problem with too much notifications for my app and I am trying to divide single `Notification` to `RemoteViews` with multiple `View`s and serve swipe gesture on each of them (to dismiss single `View`), but I see only option to inflate `View` and `setOnTouchListener` on inflated View, but it doesn't detect touch on those views in any way:

```
public class CustomNotification {

RemoteViews remoteViewsSmall;
RemoteViews remoteViewsBig;
Context context;

public CustomNotification(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        RemoteViews remoteViewsSmall = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_main);
        this.remoteViewsSmall = addLine(remoteViewsSmall);
        RemoteViews remoteViewsBig = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_main);
        this.remoteViewsBig = addLine(remoteViewsBig);
        LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = ((LinearLayout) ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.notification_main, null));
        linearLayoutParent.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> detectMove(event));
        for (int i = 0; i < linearLayoutParent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View childAt = linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(i);
            childAt.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> detectMove(event));
        }
        LinearLayout linearLayout1stLine = ((LinearLayout) ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.notification_line, linearLayoutParent));
        linearLayout1stLine.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> detectMove(event));
        for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout1stLine.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View childAt = linearLayout1stLine.getChildAt(i);
            childAt.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> detectMove(event));
        }
        View viewBig = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(remoteViewsBig.getLayoutId(), null);
        View viewSmall = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(remoteViewsSmall.getLayoutId(), null);
        LinearLayout parentLinearLayoutBig = viewBig.findViewById(R.id.notificationParentLinearLayout);
        parentLinearLayoutBig.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> detectMove(event));
        for (int i = 0; i < parentLinearLayoutBig.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View childAt = parentLinearLayoutBig.getChildAt(i);
            childAt.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> detectMove(event));
        }
        LinearLayout parentLinearLayoutSmall = viewSmall.findViewById(R.id.notificationParentLinearLayout);
        parentLinearLayoutSmall.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> detectMove(event));
        for (int i = 0; i < parentLinearLayoutSmall.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View childAt = parentLinearLayoutSmall.getChildAt(i);
            childAt.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> detectMove(event));
        }
    }

 private boolean detectMove(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i("TAG", event.getAction() + " detected");
        return true;
    }

    private RemoteViews addLine(RemoteViews remoteView) {
        RemoteViews remoteViewLine = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_line);
        remoteViewLine.setTextViewText(R.id.notification1stLine1stRowTxtView, "some string1");
        remoteViewLine.setTextViewText(R.id.notification1stLine2ndRowTxtView, "some string2");
        remoteView.addView(R.id.notificationParentLinearLayout, remoteViewLine);
        return remoteViewLine;
    }
}
```

That's the main parent layout of notification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/notificationParentLinearLayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

This below is added in `addLine` method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification1stLine1stRowTxtView"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="Example text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification1stLine2ndRowTxtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="Example text" />

</LinearLayout>
```